# Partial declarations, must not specify different base classes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know there is information about this on the internet and I've searched for it. But I'm still getting the error, can anyone point out to me what I'm doing wrong?

Base class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace ProgramManagementV2.screens
{
    public abstract class AScreenUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public string GetScreenDescriptionName()
        {
            return "No name yet!";
        }
    }
}
```

MainUserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProgramManagementV2.screens.MainUserControl"
             xmlns:we="clr-namespace:ProgramManagementV2.screens"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="textBlock1" Text="asdfasdf" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainUserControl.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ProgramManagementV2.screens
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainUserControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainUserControl : AScreenUserControl
    {
        public MainUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm adding

```
xmlns:we="clr-namespace:ProgramManagementV2.screens"
```

to the user control xml but I'm still getting the error:

> Partial declarations of 'ProgramManagementV2.screens.MainUserControl' must not specify different base classes

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By using `<UserControl ...` you claim the base-class to be `UserControl`, you would need to change it to

```
<we:AScreenUserControl x:Class="ProgramManagementV2.screens.MainUserControl" ...
```

However `UserControls` only allow one level of inheritance i think, at least if the `AScreenUserControl` has a XAML this surely will not work.

Comment: This works, but now I've lost visual studio design view. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork: I don't know, the VS designer is crap, i do not use it. Maybe you can find some question about that on SO somewhere...

Comment: Found the problem, the problem was that AScreenUserControl is abstract, visual studio could not make an instance of it and it crashed. Making it non-abstract doesn't seem like a real solution tough...

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork: UserControls rely on their base class being non-abstract though, it's not just the designer as far as i know.

Comment: If you're interested, I've found a workaround:
http://www.itscodingtime.com/post/The-WPF-designer-does-not-support-abstract-classes.aspx

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork: Well, i personally wouldn't want to disfigure my code with compiler instructions just for that but it is an interesting hack-around.

Comment: The DEBUG conditional compiler symbol is not even the right way to do that. See [Design-Time Mode](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/61858/Detect-Design-Time-Mode-in-WPF).

Comment: nope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873008/myusercontrol-cannot-be-the-root-of-a-xaml-file-because-it-was-defined-using-xam

Comment: @xoxox: "nope" to what and why?

Answer (score 5):

Just do this:

```
<we:AScreenUserControl x:Class="ProgramManagementV2.screens.MainUserControl"
             xmlns:we="clr-namespace:ProgramManagementV2.screens"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="textBlock1" Text="asdfasdf" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</we:AScreenUserControl>
```

Comment: "we:AScreenUserControl cannot be the root of a XAML file because it was defined using XAML"

Comment: not supported http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873008/myusercontrol-cannot-be-the-root-of-a-xaml-file-because-it-was-defined-using-xam