# How to use abstract classes inside a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, overriding

I have a `UserControl`.

I want each `UserControl` to Override an Abstract method.

This is my abstract class:

```
public class MyAbstract
{
    public virtual void LoadData()
    {

    }
}
```

This my usercontrol with my latest attempt at getting this to work:

```
public partial class ucAbstract : UserControl, MyAbstract
{
    public ucAbstract()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override void LoadData()
    {
        base.Load();
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Class 'ucAbstract' cannot have multiple base classes: 'UserControl' and 'MyAbstract'

How can I do this?

ADDITIONAL:
I may have to remove this addition and create a new question.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

My main form contains 2 `UserControls`: `ucOne`, `ucTwo`

Both of these controls have a method called 'LoadData'.

I have a function in my main form:

```
void LoadControl(iuserControl myUserControl)
{
    myUserControl.LoadData();
}
```

Comment: MyAbstract needs to iherit `UserControl`. You can't inherit multiple classes at the same time in C#. You have to chain the inheritance in a hierarchical way. Sorry if there's a better term to use.

Comment: C# does not have multiple inheritance

Comment: `MyAbstract` *isn't* `abstract`, and your `ucAbstract` class is attempting to inherit from two base class, which isn't possible in C#.

Comment: @TyCobb Thanks. I understand what you mean

Comment: @d.moncada thank you

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I though just by prefixing the method with 'virtual' it makes it abstract? Should I declare the class as abstract then? thanks

Comment: `virtual` just means you can override it, but also have code in the base body. `abstract` means you just have a signature and the inheritor *has* to override it.

Comment: Virtual and abstract don't mean the same thing. An `abstract` class is one that cannot be instantiated directly, and *may* have `abstract` members. Any class deriving from an `abstract` class *must*  override any `abstract` members of its base class. Concrete classes can have `virtual` members, which inheriting classes may *optionally* override.

Comment: @bothOfYou shows how useless i am.  I thought it was the other way round - thanks

Comment: @AndrewSimpson . . See my answer below.   Hope it will help you. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this.

Create a Base `class` that contains all the common methods of your `UserControl`.  Make sure that it is extended with `UserControl` class

**MyAbstract.cs**

```
public abstract class MyAbstract   : UserControl
{
    public virtual void LoadData()
    {

    }
}
```

then create a `UserControl` and extend that with `MyAbstract` class. You can use like this.

**ucAbstract.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ucAbstract : MyAbstract
{
    public ucAbstract()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override void LoadData()
    {
        base.LoadData();
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Also,  you need to have `<local:MyAbstract>` instead of `<UserControl>` in the xaml

**ucAbstract.xaml**

```
<local:MyAbstract x:Class="YourNamespace.ucAbstract"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>
</local:MyAbstract>
```

**Note:**

- You can create multiple `UserControl`s with `MyAbstract` as BaseClass.
- `UserControls` only allow one level of inheritance, at least if
  the `MyAbstract` has a XAML this surely will not work.

**Reference:**  [Partial declarations, must not specify different base classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039970/partial-declarations-must-not-specify-different-base-classes)

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. i was almost there in 1 of my attempts. I had done as you had said but I had not marked the class as abstract - also thanks for link

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't support multiple inheritance and you cannot inherit from multiple classes (`UserControl` and `MyAbstract`). You could use [`interface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx) instead of class like this:

```
public interface IMyAbstract
{
    void LoadData();
}
```

Then you should implement the interface like this:

```
public partial class ucAbstract : UserControl, IMyAbstract
{
   public void LoadData()
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. As this will work for me. I a can accept in 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You actually need `ICommand` object with proper `CommandParameter` for conditional loading, in place of your `LoadData()` method.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson wonderful tutorial http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFCustomCommands_2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can Create your UserControl

```
Public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
public virtual LoadData()
{
// ...
}
}
```