# Different base class in the XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class called `BIFUserControl` which inherits from `UserControl` class. Now I am designing a new user control called `BIFText` which inherits from `BIFUserControl` class. So, I changed the XAML file called `BIFText.xaml` as follows :

```
<base:BIFUserControl 
              xmlns:base="clr-namespace:BaseInputFramework.BaseWidgets;assembly=BaseInputFramework"
              x:Class="BIFWidgetLibrary.Text.BIFText"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 

              xmlns:mp="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Multipoint.Sdk.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Multipoint.Sdk.Controls"
              xmlns:utils="clr-namespace:BaseInputFramework.BaseWidgets.Utils;assembly=BaseInputFramework"

              mc:Ignorable="d" 
              d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="150">
     <Grid>


     </Grid> </base:BIFUserControl>
```

And then I changed my `BIFText.xaml.cs` file as follows:

```
 namespace BIFWidgetLibrary.Text {
     public partial class BIFText : BIFUserControl
     {
         public BIFText()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }
     } }
```

But now when I try to build the project, I get the following error message :
`'BaseInputFramework.BaseWidgets.BIFUserControl' cannot be the root of a XAML file because it was defined using XAML. Line 2 Position 14.`

Can someone please help me with this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your `BIFUserControl` have some xaml file too for its template or you have only subclass it from UserControl?

Comment: Yes the `BIFUserControl` class has its own XAML file as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error says itself that `BaseInputFramework.BaseWidgets.BIFUserControl` cannot be root of a XAML file since it is defined using XAML. Only elements which are not defined using XAML file can only be root element. Refer to these links - [Cannot define root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873008/myusercontrol-cannot-be-the-root-of-a-xaml-file-because-it-was-defined-using-xam) and [Inheriting from UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269106/inheriting-from-a-usercontrol-in-wpf)

Comment: Yes you are write, I quickly made a new Base UserControl class without a XAML file. And after that the above code works for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`UserControls` work by setting the `Content` to what you define in XAML, this might be the reason why you cannot inherit like that: The base class' content would be overwritten.

If you don't mind completely replacing the content you might as well use a custom control and define a [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) instead.