# wpf derive from derived control

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, user-controls, derived-class

I want to derive a control from a derived user control but having problems with the xaml resolving it.  However, first the simple scenario.  I have a library MyControls.dll.  In that, I have a control based on "UserControl" in a .cs file such as

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl { ... }
```

No problem.  Now, I want to create a second (VISUAL) control derived from this...  So, I do a new UserControl called NewFromMyUserControl.xaml.cs and NewFromMyUserControl.cs respectively in this same MyControls.dll library such as

```
public partial class NewFromMyUserControl : MyUserControl { ... }
```

Now, in the Xaml, I have...

```
<mylib:MyUserControl x:Class="MyControls.SubFolder1.NewFromMyUserControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mylib ="clr-namespace:MyControls" (blah blah) />
</mylib:MyUserControl>
```

This works no problem.  And for simplicity purposes, no actual code in the "MyUserControl" or the "NewFromMyUserControl" classes... just testing derived implementation.

NOW, the problem.  I have another library  "MyBaselineControls.dll" which has the actual UserControl I want derived from... such as

```
public class MyBaselineUserControl : UserControl { ... }
```

and Now, I want to change the "MyUserControl" to be derived from this other such as

```
from
    public class MyUserControl : UserControl { ... }
to
    using MyBaselineControls;
    public class MyUserControl : MyBaselineUserControl { ... }
```

As soon as this one line changed, the compiler fails stating...

Error   2   'MyControls.MyUserControl' cannot be the root of a XAML file because it was defined using XAML. Line 1 Position 19. ... blah blah

Are there issues of deriving from derived of another library?

Thanks

Comment: It seems this is not supported, based on this question and it's duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873008/myusercontrol-cannot-be-the-root-of-a-xaml-file-because-it-was-defined-using-xam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't derive from user controls that have a XAML definition. As long as you don't define XAML in your base class, you'll be fine. Specific information about your error can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957231).

One way to work around it is to derive from `Control` (or another class derived from `Control` which is not `UserControl`) and define a control template for your base and derived controls. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx) explains exactly what you can do when you inherit from `Control` or `UserControl`, and which things you should consider when deciding on which you'd like to derive from.

---

**EDIT**

Since you're saying that both `MyBaselineUserControl` and `MyUserControl` don't define any XAML, things should work. I tried it myself and I had no problems.

I recommend that you make sure that your base UserControls were actually created with no XAML, i.e. they should have been created with **"Add --> Class"** and not with "Add --> User Control".

Comment: That's the point... Both the baseclass in the "MyBaselineControls" and the "MyUserControl" are both -code only-... Only the "NewFromMyUserControl" one is the first VISUAL control that uses xaml.. the other two do not.

Comment: Did you create them in two separate class libraries... ie: the "MyBaseline" is one class lib, and the "MyUserControl" is in a second, and the "NewFromMyUserControl" is in the same second library as "MyUserControl"?

Comment: After having it down for the weekend and coming back to it, it finally recompiled without error (as I hoped it would originally).  Thanks for confirming I wasn't nuts in my thinking.