# Exposing Child Control Dependency Properties for Binding in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I have a very simple `UserControl` called `CustomTextBox` with this XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomTextBox" ... >
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="InnerTextBox"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now when I use `CustomTextBox` and want to do binding to `InnerTextBox.Text`, it does not work:

```
... {Binding ElementName=CustomTextBox, Path=InnerTextBox.Text}
```

I tried it another way, does not work as well:

```
... {Binding ElementName=CustomTextBox.InnerTextBox, Path=Text}
```

I know I can define **a new** dependency property called `CustomTextBox.Text` and then bind it to `InnerTextBox.Text` but I am planning to have custom controls with many properties and it is hell of a work to copy **all of them** just to support binding. Furthermore, copying/wrapping properties means each value is stored twice.

In WinForms, this was a matter simple inheritance and all the properties were available automatically. In WPF, inheritance of XAML controls is not possible and the properties are inaccessible.

Is there any simple way on how to set up binding from some control to `UserControl`'s child element property?

Comment: you should use a new dependency property anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an official way to do this? I've read a book about WPF 4 and not found anything about this. I have not found a guidelines on "copying properties" or "exposing dependency properties" on MSDN either.

Comment: 1.in the code behind of your control create a new DP ,say we call it Text 
2. in the xaml from your code : 
    <TextBox x:Name="InnerTextBox" Text={Binding Text}/>
3.make sure that the DataContext of the textBox is the UserControl

Comment: copy it to note pad or something i cant post msg here, don't know why

Comment: I see, thanks. Only the binding should be {Binding Text2} I suppose.

Comment: the '2' was for the next step 1.2.3... but sure as you see fit

Comment: @ZSH You can write your comment as answer and I would accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.in the code behind of your control create a new DP ,say we call it Text
 2. in the xaml from your code :

```
<TextBox x:Name="InnerTextBox" Text={Binding Text}/>
```

3.make sure that the DataContext of the textBox is the UserControl

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Debug text inside the Output window of visual studio, it will give explanatory text for data binding errors.

Comment: In my project, it says: BindingExpression path error: 'Text' property not found on 'object' ''CustomTextBox' (Name='CustomTextBox')'. BindingExpression:Path=Text; DataItem='CustomTextBox' (Name='CustomTextBox'); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: It simply cannot traverse to "CustomTextBox.InnerTextBox.Text" - it always takes "CustomTextBox.Text" instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a Inheritance. Your not creating the custom control properly. In Wpf Coustom Control there two parts

1. C# part->Behavior of the control. In C# part you can do the Inheritance
2. Xaml Part->UI or appearance of the control

refer the below links for more deatils

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17830/Creating-and-consuming-a-custom-WPF-control

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49802/Create-a-WPF-Custom-Control-Part-2

http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html

Comment: Controls with XAML cannot be inherited - just controls with code-behind only, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269106/inheriting-from-a-usercontrol-in-wpf

Comment: In my project, both the base and derived controls are custom controls with both XAML and code-behind...