# c# WPF XAML - Working with abstract UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, generic-programming

Hi i am actually working on a WPF Library which provides a MainWindow with different basefunctionalities. The Integrator, wich uses the Component does actually Create this Window, to working with it must provide a CostomUserControl which inherits from "*UcDatasourceBase*". This Control will be placed in the middle of the mainwindow, but i do **not** know the effective Type of the CustomUserControl, only that it's implementing *UcDatasouceBase*.

Thats the way the CodeBehind of *UcDatasourceBase* looks like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for UcDatasourceBase.xaml
/// </summary>
public abstract partial class UcDatasourceBase : UserControl
{
    public IDatasource Datasource { get; private set; }

    public UcDatasourceBase(IDatasource datasource)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And how i Integrated the Control in XAML (this causes a Compiler error):

```
<Controls:UcDatasourceBase x:Name="_ucDatasourceBase" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,13,5,7" Grid.Row="2" />
```

In the Constructor of Mainwindow I finally want to set the Control by name:

```
    public MainWindow(UcDatasourceBase ucDatasourceBase)
    {
        _UcDatasourceBase = ucDatasouceBase;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

***So how do i add Abstract Controls into xml without getting an Error?***

Links i checked before:

- [Inheriting from a Usercontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269106/inheriting-from-a-usercontrol-in-wpf)

Im Using .NET Framework 4.5 in Visual Studio 2012 Premium

**EDIT:**

The type "UcDatasourceBase" is abstract and must include an explicit value.

Comment: What is error can you share?

Comment: @jamaxack I have added the Error, but when googling it, i also might not find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `ContentControl` in xaml, and set it:

`<ContentControl x:Name="DataControl" />`

Later in your code:

`DataControl.Content = ucDatasourceBase;`