# Inheritance of a userControl from another one in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I code in wpf c#

```
partial class A : userControl
{
}

partial class B : userControl 
{
}
```

But i have to make an inheritance between them

```
partial class A : userControl
{
}

partial class B : A
{
}
```

But when i do that i have an error saying :

```
Partial declarations of B must not specify different base classes
```

Comment: Look here: [Inheriting from a UserControl in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269106/inheriting-from-a-usercontrol-in-wpf). In short, you cannot inherit from a user control that has a XAML file. You need to create a plain C# class as the base class

Comment: @Clemenes This post by itself is useful to newer WPF programmers who are trying the same approach as what OP described. The first thing comes to a programmer's mind is to change the base class. After changing the base class, he encounters this error. And my answer explains the reason for this error. The question should be reopnned.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot inherit from a user control that has a XAML file. You need to create a plain C# class as the base class:

```
// File: A.cs
public class A : UserControl
{
    public A()
    {
        // create your controls programmatically
    }
}
```

Then in your sub class's XAML file:

```
// File: B.xaml
<local:A x:Class="WpfApp1.B"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</local:A>
```

(replace `WpfApp1` with your namespace, obviously)

Note that the root tag name is `local:A` instead of `UserControl`. This identifies your control's base class. The `x:Class=...` part specifies the class name of the inherited user control.